How do I add a new layer from my QGIS project to a Kart repository?
I have created a repository using the QGIS Kart plugin, and initialized it from a GeoPackage I created using the "Package layers" tool. My source data is in ESRI File Geodatabse format.
Now I have created two new layers by reprojecting existing layers. How do I add these new layers to my Kart repository so that I can commit the change?

